# Thousand Separator in the numeric keyboard

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to create a TextBox for entering an ip adress. My first attempt was to use the `InputScope` parameter like this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtIpAdress" InputScope="Number"/>
```

The problem with that is that here in Denmark we use , (comma) Decimal Seperator and . (dot) as Thousand Separator, so when I show the numeric keyboard I got the numbers [0..9] + comma.

Can I some how force the numeric keyboard to show a . (dot) or can I show the regulare keybord and switch it over to the numeric mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you long press the dot key you will get the option which will have comma,dot and hyphen in the numeric keyboard. See the image below.[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I would very much prefer a solution where the dot is visible right away, because of the education leve of my users.

Comment: Please see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048817/windows-phone-keyboard-comma-dot-conflict

Comment: It seems like there is no good solution for this problem. I'll stick with you initial suggestion.